# How to use returned AJAX data on another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an Ajax call that returns some json data when it is successful.

This data needs to be displayed on another page that user will be redirected to.

```
window.location.replace('http://example.com/newpage');
```

And on this page the data should be displayed.

Apart from sessions/cookies is there any other way to carry this data? Or is sessions the normal way this is done?

Comment: You can use local storage for this.. for more ref.check  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Post the data to the next page and real the post body.

Comment: @epascarello could you please elaborate?

Comment: HTML forms, post....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use localstorage the api. It works in the following manner:

Set an item:

`localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');`

Retrieve an item:

`localStorage.getItem('myCat');`

---

localstorage offers **string** data to be stored accross multiple browser sessions. If you want to store object and/or arrays you have to serialize/deserialize them using:

- `json.stringify()`
- `json.parse()`

Comment: I love retrieving with set!

Comment: Ye nice one :p!

Answer (score 1):

You should use your backend language to do that, as far as i know, you can't control (for security reasons) another tab or document outside the one you are using.

My solution would be, using your backend lang, redirect sending the data from the application server.

BUT, if the page you are redirecting belongs to the same domain you can do it from the localStorage as [@Willem van der Veen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52670713/6287060) said

Answer (score 0):

redirect with php then send data to page! (flash message technique)